# Why was the law about Para Aduma given in Mara?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, chukas, parah-adumah

Why out of all the 613 mitvot  was the para aduma chosen to be  'given' in Mara? 'Shom som lo 'chok' umishpat'. Chok refers to para aduma and why is it only mentioned so late in the torah after Korach. Its place should be somewhere in vayikra where other 'tumos' are  mentioned.

Comment: These seem to be 3 unrelated questions.  I'm sure you have a "shtickle Torah" to unite all of them, but you should really ask one question per post.

Comment: It sounds like five unrelated questions, actually.

Comment: The system here does not allow me to ask more than one question. So I have to put all three into one question.

Comment: @cham1, if the system is limiting the number of questions you can ask, that does not justify violating the site's guidelines in response.  People will still be interested in these topics when you can ask more questions later.  In the meantime, if you want this to be reopened, pick one of these questions to ask.

Comment: We've had the first question before. Whilst you might expect the laws of Para Aduma to appear with the others laws of Tahor and Tuma in Tazria-Metzora, it was placed here to be close to the narrative of the deaths of the two great leaders, Miriam and Aharon. This is according to Rashi. The laws is placed here in the Torah but was not given at this point, it was given on Mount Sinai with the other laws.

Comment: My question was why it was mentioned after korach not why it was before miraim. @CashCow

Comment: It is after parshat korach but not immediately after the korach story, there are some other mitzvot given after that story, most of which do make sense to be located there as they regard the watches and part of Korach's sin was about non-kohanim wanting to do parts of service that were reserved for kohanim only. The simplest explanation is that it appears on the "bridge", the section that is between the two generations

Comment: Well my answer will be that it has plenty to do with korach. Korach's 'sin' was something entirely different  although it sounds like that on the face of it. I will ask you another question. Korach argued about 'elitsofon ben uziel' why did he change it to the 'kehuna gedolah'. @CashCow

Comment: @cham1 This is a question/answer site about Judaism.  It is not a post-your-own-Devar-Torah site. If you have a Devar Torah in the form of a question-answer, that's fine (and encouraged), but it has to be presented within the guidelines of the site. One question per post. If you have overlapping questions, you can link questions to each other. If the site will not allow you to ask more than one question, wait until it does. It's preventing spam; this is for your benefit as well as everyone else's.

Comment: For what it's worth, the question is confusing in the first place. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to explain again. They were only given certain mitvot in 'moro' Why was poro aduma chosen. And why is it only mentioned in the Torah so 'late' in the day. @SethJ I have patience if you still dont understand please ask again.

Comment: Your comment above ("They were only given certain mitvot in 'moro' Why was poro aduma chosen") gives more insight to your question than the question you posted does. I have no idea what your second and third sentences in the question are doing there. Your comment above about being late in the day is also confusing - is this yet another, separate, question? Also, grammar helps.

Comment: Thank you I am pleased you now understand it. I shall edit again which may help you understand the rest of it @SethJ

Comment: @cham1, Here are some tips for making your question post as clear as possible: 1) If you're quoting a *pasuk*, identify it clearly by *perek* and *pasuk*, and quote verbatim in Hebrew and English. 2) Make sure that your actual, final question clearly expresses what you want to know, and has a question mark. 3) Read your post from the point of view of someone who doesn't yet know what your asking, who doesn't know who you are, and who you just met in the back of shul. Did you say everything you need to make that person a) know what your question is and b) care to discover answers?

Comment: ... 4) If you're referring implicitly to a statement of *Chazal* or one of the *meforshim*, make it explicit: Cite the source and quote verbatim in Hebrew and English.

Comment: Well in the shul I go to most people know the torah and all its pesukim. I do appreciate that is not the case here. I also realise that here everything has to be 'spelled' out and they are not 'dai lachakima birmiza'. But still people here are interested in learning and that says a lot for this site. @IsaacMoses

Comment: @cham1 Here, you are writing for the entire Judaism-interested internet.

Comment: @cham1 remez is only a Remez when there is a slight inkling as to what the other is saying. Not the case here. The fact that we ask for explicit references is not a chisaron of this site. It's a maaleh. Aderabeh if one can't make him self understood clearly it's mean the lack is on the side of the one presenting the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to Question 2**

Rav Hirsch states on 20:19 that their were two main "Crown highways" leading through Edom. The first and most convenient road דרך המלך was the main high road leading through the valley where there were fields and vinyards and along which the wells were dug. That is why Moshe specified the condition "we will not pass through fields or vinyards or drink the water from the well, we will stick to the highroad and not turn aside to the right and the left:.

When this was refused, the messengers asked to be allowed to use the more difficult mountain route במסילה נעלה and to pay even for any water from the mountain stream along the route, even though it is normally free for all travelers.

Thus, Edom would not have to give thaem anything at all except permission to cross the land.

Rav Hirsch says on 20:22 that this is to emphasize that the death of Aharon was solely because of what happened at Kadesh with מי מריבה and it was his time to die. Thus he would have died at this point no matter what the response of Edom had been.

**Answer to question 3**

Rav Hirsch states that Moshe is to take the mateh in order to show that he is acting as the messenger of Hashem. However, hitting the rock with the mateh would imply that this is a special intervention from Hashem as a result of the uproar. Moshe is to take the staff "show them that you are still my messenger", but speak to the rock to show that it was Hashem who led them here and

> ... the required water was already provided by Hashem at the place to
>   which He had directed them, and it mereley required a word from Moshe
>   and Aharon to the rock which would suffice for it to produce the water
>   which Hashem had placed ready for them
>
> ... without any fresh miracle, simply with a word from you, **you** are to
>   provide them with a sufficiency for their undeniably present
>   requirements.
>
> This manner of obtaining the water would have convinced the people of
>   the deep wrong they had done in accusing Moshe and Aharon of leading
>   them to this waterless place against the will of Hashem; whereas water
>   gushing fort only as a result of a blow could still leave room for the
>   assumption that their having been led into the wilderness of Tzin wa
>   originally a wilful arbitrary act on the part of Moshe and Aharon and
>   only subsequently their justified revoltand their pressing need
>   brought about the merciful miracle of Hashem.

Note that the first time in Beshalach he was instructed to hit the rock to show that this was an explicit miracle by Hashem just as the makos in Mitzraim or the splitting of the Yam Suf which also used the mateh.

Rabbi Sorotzkin in Oznayim Latorah states that the speaking actually was not to the rock but was to teach the Bnai Yisrael Torah and to raise their spiritual level to the point that they would have deserved the miracle of the water coming from the rock themselves (with no further action by Moshe). Moshe was to take the mateh as a "Plan B" only if Bnai Yisrael could not reach that level. The error was that he concluded that Bnai Yisrael could not be raised to that level and he required the explicit miracle of hitting the rock.  This should have been delayed until **after** he had attempted to raise the Bnai Yisrael to that level.

Note that this also explains why Moshe Rabbeinu was instructed to hit the rock in Beshalach, since they were not yet at the higher level.

Comment: question 2. The second time it was not moshe rabainu who sent the request but the bnai yisroel.

Comment: question 3. This very complicated answer does not address why the first time in b'shalach he did smite the rock.

Comment: @cham1 I added explicitly why the mateh was used the first time even though that was the implication of what Rav Hirsch said in Chukas.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question of why he didnt always do the talking. Either always talk or always 'hit' My question was what changed. @Sabbahillel. I have been asked to limit  my question and this has been put on hold so unless you ask them yourself I cant really carry on.

Comment: My answer to edom is entirely different. Please notice there are about five differences in the requests. @Sabbahillel. Again unless you ask the question yourself I am not allowed to answer here.

Comment: @cham1 I would suggest that you ask the three questions individually and I will then move my answers to the individual question and expand where needed.

Comment: At the moment this site does not allow me to @sabbahillel but it does allow you

Comment: @cham1 I would suggest that you register so that you can ask the questions.